# How to scroll UITableView to desired row even before visible to user?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I was wondering, is it possible to scroll the `UITableView` to desired row, even before it is visible to user, so that such scroll action is not aware to user?

Currently, here is my code to perform scrolling to desired row.

```
class ThemeTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    private var firstTime = true
 
    private func scrollRectToVisible() {
        let theme = WeNoteOptions.theme
        if let index = Theme.allCases.firstIndex(of: theme) {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
            let rect = tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath)
            tableView.scrollRectToVisible(rect, animated: true)
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        if firstTime {
            firstTime.toggle()
            scrollRectToVisible()
        }
    }
```

Please note that, placing `scrollRectToVisible` in the following functions will not work. So far, `viewDidAppear` is the only place for `scrollRectToVisible` to work.

- `viewDidLoad` - `scrollRectToVisible` doesn't work here.
- `viewWillAppear` - `scrollRectToVisible` doesn't work here.

Here's is the outcome so far.

[image]

User will notice the auto scroll action.

We would like the scroll action not aware to user.

Is it possible that when `UITableView` is visible to user for the first time, the last row (green Avocado) is already visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your cells may have dynamic heights, you may find this more reliable:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    if firstTime {
        if tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) != 0 {
            firstTime = false
            tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) - 1, section: 0), at: .bottom, animated: false)
        }
    }
}
```

Test it with the following example... cells will have between 2 and 6 lines of text in the label. Comment / un-comment the different methods in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`:

```
class MyTableVC: UITableViewController {
    
    private var firstTime = true

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(MyCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "myCell")
    }
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        if firstTime {
            if tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) != 0 {
                firstTime = false
                
                // note the difference between this
                tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) - 1, section: 0), at: .bottom, animated: false)
                
                // and this
                //scrollRectToVisible()
            }
        }
    }
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 30
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCell
        let n = indexPath.row % 5
        var s = "Row \(indexPath.row)"
        for i in 0...n {
            s += "\n\(i)"
        }
        c.theLabel.text = s
        return c
    }

    private func scrollRectToVisible() {
        let index = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) - 1
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
        let rect = tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath)
        tableView.scrollRectToVisible(rect, animated: false)
    }

}

class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    var theLabel = UILabel()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        theLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        theLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        theLabel.backgroundColor = .yellow
        contentView.addSubview(theLabel)
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            theLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            theLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            theLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
        ])
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I know the reason of having to check for `firstTime`. (As `viewDidLayoutSubviews` will be called multiple times within short period). But, may I know what is the reason of having to check `tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) != 0`?

Comment: @CheokYanCheng - it's not **explicitly** necessary... but it will avoid a crash in the event you reach this controller before your data source has any elements.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng for some reason i do not understand the above code is causing my uitableview scroll to some sort of limitation when the user scrolls up or down until the uitableviewcell item reaches the top or bottom of the screen after the data are presented to the user...what am i missing?

Comment: @stefanosn If this is occurring, please check to ensure that you are setting `firstTime = false` within `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`, otherwise when this function is called subsequently as the user attempts to scroll, it will continuously select that row preventing scrolling. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

```
if tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) != 0 {
  scrollRectToVisible()   
}
```

with `animated: false)`

```
tableView.scrollRectToVisible(rect, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

I called `tableView.scrollRectToVisible(rect, animated: false)` with `animated` as `false`, from `viewDidAppear` method and the result were as expected.

I have copied and changed based on your code above. Here, I have added `animated:bool` as parameter in your method `scrollRectToVisible` to control animation part as needed.

```
class ThemeTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    private var firstTime = true

    // added new parameter `animated`
    private func scrollRectToVisible(_ animated: Bool = true) {
        let theme = WeNoteOptions.theme
        if let index = Theme.allCases.firstIndex(of: theme) {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
            let rect = tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath)

            // replaced true with `animated`
            tableView.scrollRectToVisible(rect, animated: animated)
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        if firstTime {
            firstTime.toggle()
            // animation = false.
            scrollRectToVisible(false)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Here consider itemCount = last item of your array

Add code in viewDidload method after your array contains data.

tableView.reloadData()
let indexPath = IndexPath(item: itemCount, section: 0)
print("indexPath",indexPath)
tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .none, animated: false)
```